# Selenium Dynamic locators

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My question is regarding dynamic By Locators.
My Page classes usually looks like that:

```
public class MyPage {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private By myFixedLocator = By.xpath(".......");
    private String myDynamicLoactor = "//div[@id = 'someId']" +
                                      "//div[contains( @class, '<className>')]";

    public MyPage(WebDriver driver) {this.driver = driver;}

    public AnotherSuperPage getAnotherPage(String className) {
        By tmpBy = By.xpath(myDynamicLocator.replace("<className>", className));
        driver.findElement(tmpBy);
        return new AnotherSuperPage(driver);
    }

   //for example here: childOne and Two are sub classes of AnotherSuperClass
   public  AnotherChild1Page getChildOne() {return getAnotherPage("childOne");}
   public  AnotherChild1Page getChildTwo() {return getAnotherPage("childTwo")}

}
```

Locators like myDynamicLocator represents elements, the all have similar xpath structure except of the one String part.
Is there any better way to do this? As far as I understood, the By locators are final and immutible.
This is also why I don't use Page Factory, since the @FindBy annotation I can use flexible locator as in the example above.
And when I have a By locator, can I get the text inside in a smooth way? because By.toString() gives me the whole information, including "xpath"....

Answer (score 0):

You could have also achieved it by simply doing it as:

```
public AnotherSuperPage getAnotherPage(String className) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'someId']//div[contains( @class, '" + className +"')]"));
    return new AnotherSuperPage(driver);
}
```

instead of creating a string object then replacing it and storing it in another variable, though anyhow this is what happens internally, but less coding. Hope am understanding you right...

Comment: You are understanding me correct. The thing is, its all about programming style. I rather have all my locators at class top as fields, and not defined inside a method, because sometimes I need them as part of other bigger loactor
(e.g. I have a locator to a table, than I will use this locator as part of a locator to a row of the same table). 
Only thing I wanted to know, if there is a way to place them as fields and still not defining a string but a FLEXIBLE MUTABLE By field. Apparently not...